# How to match Reg No. in one workbook to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to find out a formula to match Reg No. for two workbooks.
First work book is a master book I update everyday almost, next workbook I have employees name and ID numbers only, nos are in different cells than worksheet one. I want to get master file Reg no. to match the other work book and copy the birth dates.
Basically both workbooks reg. no. to be match and add only b day to another colom.

workbook1 , A3:A200=Reg no. and L3:L200= birthdays
workbook2, A3:A200=Reg no. and I want get birthday from other workbook to J:3:200

Answer (score 0):

Look up the HLOOKUP function. :-)

J3:J200 shall have something like (take it with a grain of salt, i cannot check the precise syntax right now, maybe later):

```
=HLOOKUP(A3,workbook1!A3:A200,false)
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/hlookup-HP005209114.aspx